# Javascript pre-filled SMS to device App

Tags: javascript, sms, autofill, mobile-chrome

I'm struggling with an issue pre-filling SMS to SMS device default App from a behaviour in Javascript.

**iOS >= 8**

```
window.location.href = 'sms:' <phonenumber> '&body='  <bodytext> ;
```

**iOS == 7**

```
window.location.href = 'sms:' <phonenumber> ;
```

Note: body is not supported as far as I noticed googling around

**iOS < 7**

```
window.location.href = 'sms:' <phonenumber> ';body=' <bodytext> ;
```

**Android**

```
window.location.href = 'sms:' <phonenumber> '?body=' <bodytext> ;
```

// it works on mobile Firefox, Opera, Samsung, Chrome

Note: everything seems OK by now, but my problem is I want to trigger this behaviour automatically after a setTimeout and, in Chrome isn't working.
It's dued to CSP I guess.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
Correct me if I'm wrong.

If there's a workaround I'd be pleased to get a hint from you. 
Thank you in advance,

Henry